# Display the difference between two map layers in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, layers, mapping

I am a week 1 beginner at Google Earth Engine. I assumed that the subtract method would display the difference (the increased area) between my two layers: afterMap and beforeMap, but it does not.

```
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-95.2274658203125, 56.30841555552546],


        [-95.07228393554688, 56.37083168879506],
          [-95.47191162109375, 56.38756011275328],
          [-95.57971496582032, 56.303082617975605]]]);
          
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED");

Map.centerObject(region);

var beforeSentinel = sentinel
                  .filterBounds(region)
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-10-31');
                  
var afterSentinel = sentinel
                   .filterBounds(region)
                  .filterDate('2022-06-01', '2023-06-05');
                  
var beforeArray = waterArea(beforeSentinel, region);
var beforeArea = beforeArray[0];
var beforeMap = beforeArray[1];


var afterArray = waterArea(afterSentinel, region);
var afterArea = afterArray[0];
var afterMap = afterArray[1];

var totalArea = region.area().divide(1e6);


Map.addLayer(beforeMap, {palette:['blue']}, 'NDWI Mask: before');
Map.addLayer(afterMap, {palette:['blue']}, 'NDWI Mask: after');




//this is the code that does not work, does not display the difference between the 2 areas
var increaseMap = afterMap.subtract(beforeMap);

// Display the increase map on the map
Map.addLayer(increaseMap, {palette: '00ff00'}, 'Area Increase');







function waterArea(Imagery, region)
{

var sentinelImage = 
    Imagery.sort('SNOW_ICE_PERCENTAGE', false)
    .first()
    .clip(region);
    
// print("Sentinel image taken at = ", sentinelImage.date()); - to see both dates of images taken
    
    Map.addLayer(
    sentinelImage,
    {min: 0.0, max: 3000, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']},
    'Sentinel Imagery');
    
    var ndwi =
    sentinelImage.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
Map.addLayer(
    ndwi,
    {palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue']},
    'NDWI');
    
    
    var ndwiThreshold = ndwi.gte(0.0);
var ndwiMask = ndwiThreshold.updateMask(ndwiThreshold);
//Map.addLayer(ndwiMask, {palette:['blue']}, 'NDWI Mask');

var pixelArea =  ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6); // convert to square km
var area = ndwiMask.multiply(pixelArea)
.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), //area of each pixel * amount of pixels
  geometry: region,
  scale:10 // meters 
}).get('NDWI');
return([area, ndwiMask]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

```
var increaseMap = afterMap.subtract(beforeMap);
```

`beforeMap` and `afterMap` are either masked out or they have a value of `1`. When a pixel is masked in either of these images, the difference between them will also be masked. This means, `increaseMap` will have a value of `0` for all pixels where neither `beforeMap` or `afterMap` is masked. Otherwise, it will be masked.